# Populate drop down list from mysql in in php html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using the below code to populate drop down list in php html,

```
<?php                       
$mid="mario";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_prdy WHERE col_master_id = '$mid'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "<select name='list'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['col_of_fa'] . "'>" . $row['col_of_fa'] . "
    </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

But, I am getting internal server error. I have debugged the code and found that the issue is with the following 2 lines in the above code. There is not much information in server logs. Can you tell me what might be the issue with the following 2 lines of code?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['col_of_fa'] . "'>" . $row['col_of_fa'] . 
"/option>";
}
```

Comment: The beauty of this API is that it affords the use of parametrised queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mixing mysqli with mysql

change

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

to

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use this

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result )){
}
```

or

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result )){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['col_of_fa'] ?>" ><?php echo $row['col_of_fa'] ?>
    </option>
<?php }
```